# "ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String" when trying to get data from firebase

Tags: firebase, kotlin, classcastexception

I am trying to get data from firebase and to put on recycle view, I face an error in rec view, Kotlin

I tested the recycle view and its works well on the array data. However, it's not working with firebase:

```
var db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

db.child("cart").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {

    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        var values = (p0!!.value) as HashMap<String, Any>
        for (k in values.keys) {
            var data = values[k] as HashMap<String, Any>
            carts.add(
                cart(
                    data["name"] as String,
                    data["size"] as String,
                    data["date"] as String
                )
            )
        }

        val adapter = adapter(carts)
        rec.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

> `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `java.util.HashMap` cannot be cast to `java.lang.String`

Comment: Are you sure the contents of the name/size/date fields are all strings and not HashMaps themselves? Try debugging or logging the value of data["name"]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo and indicate the exact line of code at which the error occurs.

Comment: Recreating your adapter every change is likely quite inefficient. I would switch to using FirebaseUI (it will handle updates for you).

Comment: solved .....the issue was on the firebase connection, I changed the rule as below                                             {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null", //even non-authorised users CAN read
    ".write": "auth == null" //even non-authorised users CAN write
  }
}